# How should I find the analytical form of these recursive equations

Tags: recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

I have

$$x_1(t+1) = (1-m \rho_1)x_1(t) + n\rho_2 x_2(t) + h1$$

$$x_2(t+1) = (1-m \rho_2)x_2(t) + n\rho_1 x_1(t) + h2$$

Suppose $x_1(0)$ and $x_2(0)$ are known. How can I find the analytical form of $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$? I know without the recursion it is

$$ x_1(t) = (1-m\rho_1)^t x_1(0) + \frac{1-(1-m\rho_1)^t}{m\rho_1}h_1 $$

but the recursive form makes it too complicated.

PS

Actually I want to compute the derivative $\frac{\partial R}{\partial \rho_1}$ with  $R=\sum_t^T x_1(t)$. Perhaps some terms could be removed from the beginning?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Define generating functions $X_1(t) = \sum_{t \ge 0} x_1(t) z^t$ and $X_2(t) = \sum_{t \ge 0} x_2(t) z^t$, mutiply your recurrences by $z^t$ and sum over $t \ge 0$. Then recognize the resulting sums:
\begin{align}
\frac{X_1(z) - x_1(0)}{z}
  &= (1 - m \rho_1) X_1(z) + n \rho_2 X_2(z) + \frac{h_1}{1 - z} \\
\frac{X_2(z) - x_2(0)}{z}
  &= (1 - m \rho_2) X_1(z) + n \rho_1 X_2(z) + \frac{h_2}{1 - z}
\end{align}
Solve this for $X_1(z)$ and $X_2(z)$, express them as partial fractions and use the generalized binomial theorem to get the coefficients:
$$
\binom{-n}{k} = \binom{k + n - 1}{n - 1} (-1)^k
$$
A computer algebra system, like [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net), is a must if you are prone to stupid mistakes (like I am).